# Selecting n-elements of each class

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I'm using pandas, I have a set of data with about 4 milion of observations. 
I was wondering what is the best / fastest / the most efficient way to select 50 random elements or first 50 elements for each class (class is just a column).

The unique number of classes in my column is about ~2k, and I would like to select a subset of 100,000 elements, 50 elements for each class.

I was thinking about grouping them into class, then iterating through each group and selecting first 50 elements, then proceeding to next group.

I was wondering is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 2), columns=list('ab'))
df['group'] = np.remainder(np.random.permutation(len(df)), 3)

df.head()

    a           b           group
0   0.069140    0.553955    1
1   0.564991    0.699645    2
2   0.251304    0.516667    2
3   0.962819    0.314219    2
4   0.353382    0.500961    0
```

you can get a randomized version by

```
df_randomized = df.ix[np.random.permutation(len(df))]

df_randomized.head()

    a           b           group
90  0.734971    0.895469    0
35  0.195013    0.566211    0
27  0.370124    0.870052    2
21  0.297194    0.500713    1
66  0.319668    0.347365    2
```

To select N random elements, first generate the permutation and reduce it in size. After that apply it to the dataframe:

```
N = 10
indexes = np.random.permutation(len(df))[:N]
df_randomized = df.ix[indexes]
```

To get the first N elements of each group you can group the dataframe and apply a method to select the first N elements. No need of any loops here as pandas can handle that for you:

```
N = 10
df.groupby('group')\
    .apply(lambda x: x[:N][['a', 'b']])
```

All of those methods should be fast as they use the internal optimised methods of either numpy or pandas.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you need to use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
               'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,12]})


Samplesize = 2  #number of samples that you want       
print df.groupby('class', as_index=False).apply(lambda array: array.loc[np.random.choice(array.index, Samplesize, False),:])
```

input

```
    class  value
0       0      1
1       1      2
2       2      3
3       3      4
4       0      5
5       1      6
6       2      7
7       3      8
8       0      9
9       1     10
10      2      1
11      3     12
```

output

```
      class  value
0 8       0      9
  0       0      1
1 1       1      2
  5       1      6
2 6       2      7
  10      2      1
3 11      3     12
  3       3      4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I have a class with number of observations which is smaller than my specified Samplesize I cannot use that solution. Im occuring ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'

Comment: print df.groupby('class', as_index=False).apply(lambda array: array.loc[np.random.choice(array.index, Samplesize, True),:])
use this  one , just remember that the sample may have duplicates when it  is True

Comment: @sebb You said that you want 50 elements of each class. If a class have less than 50 elements you can't have that so raising an exception looks like the right thing to do.